# solution of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the solution of this  differential equations

$${\frac {d^{2}x}{d{t}^{2}}} +\gamma\, \left[  \left( {
\frac {dx}{dt}}\right) ^{2}+ \left( {\frac {dz}{dt}}
  \right) ^{2} \right]=0$$

$${\frac {d^{2}z}{d{t}^{2}}} +g+\gamma\, \left[ 
 \left( {\frac {dx}{dt}}  \right) ^{2}+ \left( {
\frac {dz}{dt}} \right) ^{2} \right] =0$$

Comment: You can put it in hold if you want to

Answer (score 3):

Let $X(t)=x'(t)$ and let $Z(t)=z'(t)$, then we get
$$
X'(t)+\gamma(X^2+Z^2)=0
$$
$$
Z'(t)+g+\gamma(X^2+Z^2)=0.
$$
Taking the difference of the two, we get
$$
(Z(t)-X(t))' = -g.
$$
This implies that
$$
Z(t)=X(t)-gt+C.
$$
Substituting this back to the first differential equation, we get
$$
X'(t)+\gamma(X^2+(X-gt+C)^2)=0.
$$
The only unknown in this last equation is $X$. This last equation is not separable or exact. I am not quite sure how to continue from here. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Continuation of the EagleToLearn's partial answer : 
$$X'(t)+\gamma(X^2+(X-gt+C)^2)=0.$$
$$
X'(t)=-\gamma\left(2X^2+2(-gt+C)X+(-gt+C)^2\right).
$$
This is a Riccati ODE. The convenient change of function is : $\quad X(t)=\frac{Y'}{2\gamma Y}$

$\frac{Y''}{2\gamma Y}-\frac{(Y')^2}{2\gamma Y^2}= -2\gamma\left(\frac{Y'}{2\gamma Y}\right)^2+2\gamma(gt-C)\frac{Y'}{2\gamma Y}-\gamma(gt-C)^2$

$\frac{Y''}{2\gamma Y}= 2\gamma(gt-C)\frac{Y'}{2\gamma Y}-\gamma(gt-C)^2$
$$\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} -2\gamma(gt-C)\frac{dY}{dt}+2\gamma^2(gt-C)^2Y(t)=0$$
Change of variable : $\quad \theta=(gt-C)^2\quad$ After transformation :
$$\frac{d^2Y}{d^2\theta} +(1-\frac{2\gamma}{g}) \frac{dY}{d\theta}+\frac{\gamma^2}{g^2}Y(\theta)=0$$
This is a linear ODE easy to solve :

$Y(\theta)=c_1\exp\left(\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right)\theta\right) +c_2\exp\left(\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12-\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right)\theta\right)$

$$Y(t)=c_1\exp\left(\pm\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right) \sqrt{gt-C} \right) \\+c_2\exp\left(\pm\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12-\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right)\sqrt{gt-C}\right)$$
$$x'(t)=X(t)=\frac{1}{2\gamma}\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt} \quad\implies\quad x(t)=\frac{1}{2\gamma}\ln|c_3Y|$$
With $C_1=c_1c_3$ and $C_2=c_2c_3$ , the result is :
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2\gamma}\ln\left| C_1\exp\left(\pm\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right) \sqrt{gt-C} \right) \\+C_2\exp\left(\pm\left(\frac{\gamma}{g}-\frac12-\sqrt{\frac12-\frac{\gamma}{g} } \right)\sqrt{gt-C}\right)\right|$$
The constants and the correct sign of $\pm$ have to be determined according to some conditions (not specified in the wording of the question).

Note (depending on the missing conditions) : For some conditions the above arduous calculus might become much simpler.

Comment: first thank you for your answer, but i try to check the solution and
put die solution for $\dot{x}\,,\dot{z}$ and $\ddot{x}\,,\ddot{z}$ in my differential equations the result must be zero ? but it isn't. Did you check your solution? 
also to get $z(t)$ i have to integrate $\dot{z}$ there isn't close solution for the integration. all is done with Maple Program

Comment: I checked nothing. I even not checked the EagleToLearn's calculus. The aim of my answer was only to show how to solve the Riccati equation. You should do again the whole and correct it if there is a mistake.